# Does wishing to have a life and friends like in animation movies amount to shirk?

Tags: shirk, doubts, waswasa

I have waswas problem; recently I've been having doubts when watching animation movies.  When I was watching that movie, I felt like I wish I could have life like in the movie and friends like this.  I wish I would get friends that look like this: is thinking like this shirk?

Whatever I do, I feel like I'm doing shirk now; I could not understand which is shirk and which is normal. I am not comparing anything with Allah but I still feel like am doing something wrong by liking thing which are not created by Allah.  I am so confused please tell is it normal thought or shirk or some other sin.

Comment: Why do you think that is shirk? How do you define shirk?

Answer (score 0):

If these movies cause you so much trouble maybe you shouldn't watch them, maybe you should go for a walk.

Also, take care of your hygiene, it has a great effect on these matters.

"O you who covers himself! Rise and warn! And your Lord magnify! And your garments purify! And from filth distance thy! And don't ask for return-favors to multiply! And for your Lord stand by!" - Al-Muddathir

Answer (score -1):

If you were wishing for such life, and as soon as you understood what you are doing that is being ungrateful to Allah, you stopped and repented and said no I am very happy with what I got subhanallah, inshAllah it is not shirk. If you had that thought and persisted in it , that is kufr, for you are being ungrateful to Allah, not being thankful, and you are not liking or appreciating what Allah gave you, that is arguing or being against Allah , astaghfirullah, or declining the fact that he is not all knower, astaghfirullah, is shirk also, declining or associating any of the 99 name of Allah is shirk and kufr,  and all knower is one of them, so by saying that you are actually saying that you know more than Allah what is right or wrong for you,which you don't. So that will be shirk and kufr, but if that is a random thought popping in your head, and you are fighting against it, it is nafs pr wasawaas , and Allah has said he will reward us for fighting against it. InshAllah you got your answer.
Allah knows the best.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is wrong. The correct answer is it's jealousy, it can be of 2 types. A malicious one or non malicious one, you can check more on jealousy, I Had the same problem.